# Spring data - how to order by a property inside a subclass

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

I'm new to Spring data, I would like to know how to solve the following situation:

I have a class Product which has inside a property of the class Model, this subclass has a property "price".
My goal is to have a method that returns all the products ordered by "price", but as the property price is inside the subclass Model instead of the class Product, I don't know how to do it.

Previously I had the price directly inside the class product so in my  JPARepository i had:

```
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product,Long> {





List<Product> findByOrderByPriceDesc();

List<Product> findByOrderByPriceAsc();
 }
```

But now as the property price has been moved to the class Model, I don't know how to modify the signature of these methods to adapt it to the change in the datamodel.

Could you please help me out?

Comment: I'm currently at the bus, so i cant verify this, but i would excpect that it works the same way as findBy property of a subclass: findBySublassProperty (not sure if there has to be an underscore between Name of the Subclass fieldname and its property Name)

Comment: Use a repository for the concrete subclass or move the price field up to the Product class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm at home now and tried it.

It works as expected:

```
findByPropertyOrderBySubclassProperty(Property property);
```

I created a sample project and put it on Github: https://github.com/Yannic92/stackOverflowExamples/tree/master/SpringBoot/OrderByNestedSubclassProperty

Please let me know if this helped :)

Comment: Wow.. That's easy! Spring data rocks! Thank you... By the way. never seen the annotation @RepositoryRestResource before, This is to mark the repo as a repo to be called from a rest client? what is the benefit of using this annotation?  ,

Comment: Oh no. Its not necessary. Its options are usefull. For example the Export or the excerptProjection property. I use it for clarification. I will remove it tomorrow to prevent confusion :) for me it's time to sleep now. 6 hours till the alarm goes down :/